Make linker create different bin for each MEMORY region
I have linker based on llvm (but also answers for gcc would be helpful), used for embedded product.
In my product I have two different memory regions in different address space, one for code and other for  literals. hence my linker file looks like:
MEMORY
   {
       code_region: ORIGIN = <start_address1>, LENGTH = <length1>
       lit_region: ORIGIN = <start_address2>, LENGTH = <length2>
   }
SECTIONS
   {
       .code_section :
       {
           /* content */
       } > code_region

       .lit_section :
       {
           /* content */
       } > lit_region
   }

The problem is that the linker create one bin file for it, padding all addresses between with zero.
I can take this file and cut it to two files, I want to know if there is a way to get it as two binaries straight from the linker without cutting)

Can you use llvm-objcopy for this?
